# IF condition do not display modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to inject a CSS `display: none` if `cursor` is not empty? Using show: false just hides the model but a transparent overlay remains.

```
function checkCookie() {
  var cuser = getCookie("cuser");
  if (cuser == "") {
  jQuery('#modalWin').modal({show: true, backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
 }
}
```

Comment: You should just put `#modalWin { display: none; }` in the CSS. jQuery will override this when you want to show it.

Comment: @Barmar great solution. did not know JQuery would override it...